# Validate Fedex Location Search Request

Tags: web-services, fedex

We have integrated Fedex API in a ruby on rails application .

We need nearest drop off locations . We want to filter locations by DANGEROUS_GOODS_SERVICES.

We have checked the fedex locationService pdf file and we found the following xml request format that we are requesting .

**Request**

```
  <SearchLocationsRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/locs/v3">
  <UserCredential>
    <Key>XXXXXXXXXXXX</Key>
    <Password>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Password>
  </UserCredential>
  <WebAuthenticationDetail/>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>XXXXXXXXXX</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>XXXXXXXXX</MeterNumber>
    <Region>us</Region>
  </ClientDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>locs</ServiceId>
    <Major>1</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <EffectiveDate>2016-04-13</EffectiveDate>
  <LocationsSearchCriterion>ADDRESS</LocationsSearchCriterion>
  <Address>
    <StreetLines>811 E 1950 N</StreetLines>
    <City>Spanish Fork</City>
    <StateOrProvinceCode/>
    <PostalCode>84660</PostalCode>
    <UrbanizationCode/>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <Residential>0</Residential>
  </Address>
  <PhoneNumber/>
  <GeographicCoordinates/>
  <MultipleMatchesAction>RETURN_ALL</MultipleMatchesAction>
  <SortDetail>
    <Criterion>DISTANCE</Criterion>
    <Order>LOWEST_TO_HIGHEST</Order>
  </SortDetail>
  <Constraints>
    <RadiusDistance>
      <Value>10.0</Value>
      <Units>KM</Units>
    </RadiusDistance>
  </Constraints>
</SearchLocationsRequest>
```

**Response**

```
{"SearchLocationsReply"=>{"HighestSeverity"=>"ERROR", "Notifications"=>{"Severity"=>"ERROR", "Source"=>"prof", "Code"=>"1000", "Message"=>"Authentication Failed"}, "Version"=>{"ServiceId"=>"locs", "Major"=>"1", "Intermediate"=>"0", "Minor"=>"0"}}}
```

Authentication failed message we are getting, while the same credentails are working for getting rates and labels.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than you, after several hours I discovered that the problem was some invisible characteres copied from the fedex email confirmation. In a text editor was possible to see them:

[image: Be careful with the strange characters at the begin and at the end of the key/passwords]

Be careful with the strange characters at the begin and at the end of the key/passwords.

The problem was solved after strip those characters.